# Where is the query in wp-login.php WORDPRESS

Tags: php, wordpress, content-management-system

I am making a loginform in WORDPRESS and i want to have a validation on it, so i tried to look at the wp-login.php to see how they validate things. But i did not find what i am looking for. I would like to know how they validate things or what input do they need to validate things. I tried to search the wordpress forums all i can find is plugin, plugin and more plugin. I dont want a plugin. I want to hardcode it. So please help me.

1. I want to know where you can find the part that searches for the users username and password.
2. Or if not , know what is needed for a successful login. example username or password or others.

by the way here is the [wp-login.php](http://pastebin.com/Kn416sxw). THanks

Comment: You might want to try posting this over at wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: oh yeah thanks. :) +1 for the tip

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed the auth logic is not located in `wp-login.php`.

Wordpress relies a lot on hooks ([actions and filters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API)). For authentication, [this article](http://willnorris.com/2009/03/authentication-in-wordpress-28) explain some of the process in wordpress 2.8+. AFAIK this is still the same in 3.x.

Authentication process is based on the `authenticate` filter. Two hooks are added in the filter queue :

- wp_authenticate_username_password() (priority 20) in `wp-includes/user.php` (line 68)
- wp_authenticate_cookie() (priority 30) in `wp-includes/user.php` (line 117)

See the article for more details.

I encourage you not to hack the core directly but add some hooks on this filter with higher priorities.

Answer (score 0):

Start looking on line 535:

```
case 'login' :
default:
        $secure_cookie = '';
        $interim_login = isset($_REQUEST['interim-login']);
```

That appears to be the login function. At line 630 you get what appears to be the html for the login form:

```
<form name="loginform" id="loginform" action="<?php echo esc_url( site_url( 'wp-login.php', 'login_post' ) ); ?>" method="post">
        <p>
                <label for="user_login"><?php _e('Username') ?><br />
                <input type="text" name="log" id="user_login" class="input" value="<?php echo esc_attr($user_login); ?>" size="20" tabindex="10" /></label>
        </p>
```

Make your edits and see if that works.